# Hangout - open app on load

Tags: api, google-hangouts

I have developed a hangout app and shared it with users sometime ago. Since then, I have received a lot of requests concerning the fact that the user should click de app icon to initialize it. Is there a way to open an app on hangout load? That is, open the hangout app without user interaction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add your app_id to open app on load

```
<script>
    gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div', {
        'render': 'createhangout',
        'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '297670343437', 'start_data' : '123456', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
        'hangout_type': 'onair',
        'widget_size': 175
    });
</script>
```